# How much data is increased by augmentation of Keras ImageDataGenerator?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, data-augmentation

I have a confusion regarding the implementation of augmentation techniques of ImageDataGenerator Keras.I'm doing a classification task and for this I've total 5 classes containing 1200 images each.In total, I have a dataset of 6000 image dataset.

If I apply 5 augmentation techniques, whether the techniques are applied altogether to an image or applied separately?

Will I get (6000X5)=30,000 data or will I get(6000X2)=12,000 data generated by augmentation method?

I want to apply the following augmentation techniques:

```
data_aug = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    zoom_range=.1,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    rotation_range=8,
    width_shift_range=.2,
    height_shift_range=.2)
```

Can anyone help me to figure it out?

Comment: Keras applies the augmentation in place. You will have 6000 augmented images in every epoch.

Comment: Will the augmented images be different in different epochs?

Comment: Since it applies augmentation in real time, every time it would be different.

Comment: Are the augmentation techniques applied altogether in each image?

Comment: I think yes and also I think if you apply it to some images and actually see the results, you will better understand the api and how it works.